# GCM GcmListenerService and InstanceIDListenerService

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I followed this link https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start but I didn't understand few things.

1. Where do I start `GcmListenerService` and `InstanceIDListenerService`(service), because in examples they don't start it anywhere in the code. Do these classes start automatically?

My `GcmListenerService` class:

```
public class GcmMessageReceiver extends GcmListenerService {

public GcmMessageReceiver() {
    Log.i("TEST", "GcmMessageReceiver");
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");

    Log.i("TEST", data.toString());
    Log.i("TEST", "Success!");

}
```

`GcmListenerService` manifest declaration:

```
<service
        android:name=".GcmMessageReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

My InstanceIDListenerService class:

```
public class GcmOnTokenRefresh extends InstanceIDListenerService {

public GcmOnTokenRefresh(){
    Log.i("TEST", "GcmOnTokenRefresh");
}


@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    startService(new Intent(this, RegisterTokenService.class));
    super.onTokenRefresh();
}
}
```

My `InstanceIDListenerService` manifest declaration:

```
    <service
        android:name=".GcmOnTokenRefresh"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, they start automaticaly if you write them in to AndroidManifest.xml file. Just like all other services in background.

Comment: In these services, in constructors, I try to print out some value to see if service is started(as you can see in my given code), but nothing gets printed. When these services start running?

Comment: When application recieves intent with notification, they start.

Comment: And 1 more thing, your registration service should start in your Main Activity, I forgot about it :)

Comment: @Stanislav Parkhomenko is right, I'd also mention here that you should have a look at FCM which is based on GCM but it has some extra features and much easier to implement. firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging